# How to set variable to object?

Tags: jquery

I have a static code like:

```
var LayersliderInit = function () {

    return {
        initLayerSlider: function () {
            $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
                skinsPath : '/../assets/global/plugins/slider-layer-slider/skins/',
                skin : 'fullwidth',
                thumbnailNavigation : 'hover',
                hoverPrevNext : false,
                responsive : false,
                responsiveUnder : 960,
                layersContainer : 960
            });
        }
    };

}();
```

Now I want to change skinspPth object as follows:

```
skinsPath : webroot+'/assets/global/plugins/slider-layer-slider/skins/',
```

Where webroot is defined an initialized with proper value. My entire code is:

```
var LayersliderInit = function () {
 var webroot = $('#webroot');
    return {
        initLayerSlider: function () {
            $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
                skinsPath : webroot+'/assets/global/plugins/slider-layer-slider/skins/',
                skin : 'fullwidth',
                thumbnailNavigation : 'hover',
                hoverPrevNext : false,
                responsive : false,
                responsiveUnder : 960,
                layersContainer : 960
            });
        }
    };

}();
```

But when I inspect skinsPath object it looks like:

```
skinsPath : webroot+'/assets/global/plugins/slider-layer-slider/skins/',
```

How would I set webroot variable so that it is concatenated?

Comment: Isn't `$('#webroot')` a jQuery object? Why are you trying to use it in a string?

Comment: Use eval(webroot), said webroot is a variable.

Comment: Use a string value instead of $('#webroot') object. Like  $('#webroot').val() or  $('#webroot').text();

Comment: did you want to get the value of `#webroot` maybe? something like `$('#webroot').val()`

Comment: Thanks all. It works now.

Comment: @sattar_kuet_bd - What all works now?  You never answered ANY of the questions we asked.  That is not how this site works.  You should answer our question so people can write complete answers and then you can accept the best answer and it can be used as a future reference for others.  That's how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `webroot` is a jQuery object.  It's not a string.  So your expression:

```
webroot+'/assets/global/plugins/slider-layer-slider/skins/'
```

is not going to what you want.  It will try to do some sort of string conversion on the `$('#webroot')` jQuery object and then concatenate that.  You need to explain what you expect `webroot` to be in that expression so we can help you get that value out and use it in the expression.

Do you mean to get some attribute or value off the `#webroot` object in the DOM?  Where do you expect the string value to come from?  Perhaps if you show us the HTML associated with the `#webroot` object we might have a better idea on what solution would work for you.

If `#webroot` is an `<input>` tag, then perhaps you want this:

```
webroot.val() + '/assets/global/plugins/slider-layer-slider/skins/'
```

Comment: I think this should be posted as a comment, not an answer

Comment: @TheFlash - I'm explaining why their code does not work given the information the OP has provided and offering one possible direction for a solution based on the limited information we have.  That's the best that can be done at this point.

Comment: @sattar_kuet_bd - Did this answer your question? If so, please click the green checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate that to the community and to earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.  If not, please explain what part of your question you are still confused about.